# On pgAdmin under table view/edit data why can't I type data directly into row?

Tags: pgadmin-4

I created a user table and made UserID column the primary key but when I go to the table then click view/edit data all rows it has no way to type info directly into row.

[image]

I expected to be able to go and type the information into row then be able to save it to refresh table. I was following a tutorial from Codemy on Youtube where he does it this way.

[image]

Comment: It says: "Data Output". The view for input should be somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what I was doing wrong. I needed to click 2-3 times on item I wanted to edit and a box pops up to type in the information I want to add. Then I just go to Save Data Changes (F6) and it saves it into it.